# Add values from page to form

Tags: javascript, forms

Okay so this is going to be a bit more difficult and I am not sure anymore on how to do this.

As you can see in the following image, what I am planning to do. I want potential customers to be able to build their own Depot and send us a request with those selected specifications.

So in Step 1 they select the Type. Step 2, the Wood they would like as a door. Step 3, which type of Lock they would like. And Step 4, what type of extras they would like.

Step 1 and Step 2 I added a script to change image to whatever they Click on. That will be the tricky part.

I would like for them to be able to request an offer on that exact specification at the end.

**So I need to get the Date from Step 1, 2, 3 and 4 and fill that into a form.**

The website is still pretty much raw and I want to get further on this topic, so I haven't finished a thing yet.

[image]

Comment: Your post lacks enough detail for anyone to give help that is likely to be useful. In particular, you haven't actually asked a question or provided any of your code. Please read the [question checklist](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist) and [ask] for guidance on editing your question to make it possible and easy for people to help you.

Comment: There isn't that much of a tricky part here, if you use what functionality HTML already provides. All those images you click on, should be the label of a radio button. (The radio button itself can be visually hidden.) Then clicking on those images will check the corresponding radio button, and you just have to submit the form at the end, to get all the data you need on the server side. _Additionally_ showing a larger version of the small image that you clicked on, is just visual "sugar", that doesn't have much to do with the actual functionality then.